# Is it possible to tell the frequency of the noise in this case?

Tags: oscilloscope

I have a scope screen shot from a while ago and Im not able to generate another test.
[image]

What can we say about the frequency of the ringing pulse noise by looking at this scope screen?

Comment: What are the channels? What are you trying to find? You could guesstimate a frequency for Ch3's slowest component  from the screenshot (400kHz) but you don't have the resolution for the other channels or to measure the decay of the faster features on any channel

Comment: Channels are from DC  power supply lines DC side. The data is from some weeks ago from a remote area. Im told that EMI pulse is observed sometimes across the DC power supply lines. Some suggested to try suppression by using ferrite rings. But those rings have their own freq. bandwith for attenution. Thats why I was trying to figure out the approximate freq of this interference.

Comment: How did you measure 400kHz for the purple?

Comment: When you do this the next time, are you aware that with a Rigol you can do a screen grab internally to a file? This means you end up with something rather more legible than simply taking a photo of the screen.

Comment: If I read everything correctly (it's not very sharp) then the period is about half a division, going right from the trigger point, and 1 div is 5us.  The rest is trivial. It's actually just under 1/2 a div so perhaps a little higher *f*, but I would only take a 1 significant digit estimate form this data

Comment: Im not able to see 5us per division. :(

Comment: 5us top left, after the H (for horizontal) just to the right of the STOP in red.

Comment: @Neil_UK Omg I saw it now stupid me

Comment: It looks like a at least 1MegHz at least interference then assuming EMI pulse is around 1us

Comment: I'm pitching 300-400KHz for the purple and about 3.6MHz for the ringing on the yellow and blue.  I suggest averaging all the estimates, wisdom of the crowd.

Comment: If it is EMI, is it more likely common mode or differential mode? Or is it impossible to guess?